# g++ 10.3.0: False positive or an actual problem?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, clang++

Compiling the following code with g++ 10.3 gives some fearsome warnings (see https://godbolt.org/z/excrEzjsd, too):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/algorithm/clamp.hpp>

namespace demo {
template <typename T, size_t N> constexpr std::size_t array_size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
template <std::size_t N> inline void StrCpy(std::string::value_type (&dest)[N], const std::string::value_type *src) {
    std::strncpy(dest, src, N);
    dest[N - 1] = 0; // make sure the terminating NUL is there
}

template <std::size_t N> inline void StrCpy(std::string::value_type (&dest)[N], const std::string &src) { StrCpy(dest, src.c_str()); }
} // namespace demo
int main() {
    struct a {
        int m_num_lines;
        char m_lines[6][201];
    };

    std::vector<std::string> lines{
        "Line0",
        "Line1",
        "Line2",
        "Line3",
        "Line4",
        "Line5",
        "Line6",
        "Line7",
        "Line8",
        "Line9",
        "Line10",
    };

    auto theA = std::make_shared<a>();

    theA->m_num_lines = boost::algorithm::clamp(lines.size(), 0, demo::array_size(theA->m_lines));

    for (auto i = 0; i < theA->m_num_lines; i++) {
        demo::StrCpy(theA->m_lines[i], lines[i]);
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < theA->m_num_lines; i++) {
        std::cout << theA->m_lines[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I don't understand what the compiler is actually trying to say. Do I have a bug or does the compiler see ghosts? BTW: clang++ and MSVC see nothing wrong here.

The output:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -O3 gcc.cpp -o gcc-bug
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:495,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/cstring:42,
                 from gcc.cpp:4:
In function ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘void demo::StrCpy(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::value_type (&)[N], const value_type*) [with long unsigned int N = 201]’ at gcc.cpp:10:17,
    inlined from ‘int main()’ at gcc.cpp:14:113:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:106:34: warning: ‘char* __builtin_strncpy(char*, const char*, long unsigned int)’ forming offset [1212, 1410] is out of the bounds [0, 1212] [-Warray-bounds]
  106 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In function ‘void demo::StrCpy(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::value_type (&)[N], const value_type*) [with long unsigned int N = 201]’,
    inlined from ‘int main()’ at gcc.cpp:14:113:
gcc.cpp:11:17: warning: writing 1 byte into a region of size 0 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   11 |     dest[N - 1] = 0; // make sure the terminating NUL is there
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
gcc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
gcc.cpp:19:14: note: at offset 206 to object ‘main()::a::m_lines’ with size 1206 declared here
   19 |         char m_lines[6][201];
      |              ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: What warnings do you get?

Comment: Sorry, I was working on this. The site rejected the post because of too much code.

Comment: `std::string::value_type` that's a rather peculiar way of spelling `char`.

Comment: It is complaining because you are trying to do something unkosher with type aliases, and only your GCC has bothered to do some checking for out of bounds problems. The other two compilers should have complained about using `strncpy()` and left it at that.

Comment: @Dúthomhas What exactly is unkosher?

Comment: It seems GCC unrolls the loop into seven consecutive accesses. That's obviously one beyond for `m_lines`. The Kicker is of course that the seventh unrolled iteration will be skipped since you clamped, but GCC still warns since it does an out of bound access it cannot prove will never happen.

Comment: And the unrolling is wrong even if `m_lines` is a 7x201 array. Wow, that's not a false positive, that's GCC reporting on its own sub par code generation here. I wonder if it's a known bug.

Comment: Seems to be a recurring issue with GCC. Here's a bug from 2018 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86341

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Adding -fno-peel-loops makes the warning go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica for identifying this as a compiler bug. Adding the option `-fno-peel-loops` solves the problem.